Opening Salesforce Contact Page on Call Acceptance in Custom Application
Hello Salesforce Community, I am currently working on a custom application integrated with Salesforce that handles call functionality. The application is designed to manage inbound calls and I want to implement a feature where, upon accepting a call, the corresponding Salesforce contact page opens automatically within the Salesforce UI. The application has already been tested and functions correctly for call handling, but this modification is crucial for improving the user experience.
so the thing is in softphone layout when the record match the record detail page has to open

but still the record page is not opening


Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  We  cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process.  Please [edit] your question to show us the work you've done and the specific problem you have.

So I added the SS of the problem I'm facing
